# App(TikTok) don't run app on adb emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, adb

I need to run tiktok from adb to make with it some actions using appium (or maybe there is another solution to make actions on emulator automatically?). By the way when I try to install TikTok on emulator from Android Studio, I got this error:
[image]

I tried  different  versions of androids and different Android Studio emulators and download only apk not from Play Market. Nothing helps. What should I do? Use another emulator, especially for apps from PlayMarket(I don't know this) or maybe there is some way to run TikTok on adb (configure something?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will never run on emulator. They check it. You should use Nox emulator or analogs

Answer (score 0):

try reset android emulator and remount it

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MASTER_CLEAR
adb  remount
adb install example.apk
```

Comment: Consider add an explanation as to how and why your code answers the question.